# How to use Cefsharp browser control in ExcelDNA add-in?

Tags: c#, vb.net, webbrowser-control, cefsharp, excel-dna

I creating excel add-In with [ExcelDNA](https://github.com/Excel-DNA) that contains [Cefsharp](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp) browser in [Custom task pane](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/custom-task-panes). When I run add-In, I'll get an error about:

> Could not load file or assembly "CefSharp, Version=65.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=40c4b6fc221f4138"  or one of its
>   dependencies. The specified module could not be found.

How can I fix that?

Creating user control that contains `ChromiumWebBrowser`:

```
        [ComVisible(true)]
        public class MyBrowser : UserControl
        {
            ChromiumWebBrowser browser = new ChromiumWebBrowser("www.google.com");
            browser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            this.Controls.Add(browser);
        }
```

Code for creating custom task pane:

```
        private static void CreateCTP()
        {
            ctp = CustomTaskPaneFactory.CreateCustomTaskPane(typeof(MyBrowser), 
                            "My Custom Task Pane");
            //Setting ctp params...
            ctp.Visible = true; 
        }
```

NOTE:

- All dependencies/references connected and files (`unmanaged` resources) added into `bin/Debug`.
- Add-In works normaly (if ChromiumWebBrowser not using).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[This is a known issue with CefSharp](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/351)**... It is not compatible with non-default AppDomains. You can see more details in the issue "[Multiple AppDomains error "Cannot pass a GCHandle across AppDomains](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/351)"

Excel-DNA creates a custom/non-default AppDomain for each add-in, and CefSharp doesn't like that. [Someone tried to fix CefSharp a while ago](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/pull/1556), but unfortunately the pull-request [was not accepted/merged](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/pull/1556#issuecomment-284273373) and the problem still persists. If you're brave enough, you can download that pull-request and have your own version of CefSharp, with that fix applied.

A workaround to use CefSharp as-is with Excel-DNA is to run it in separate process, in a default AppDomain. Examples of how to do it [here](https://github.com/andrewkittredge/AppHostCefSharp) and [here](https://github.com/stever/AppHostCefSharp).

You can also read more about this in this discussion: "[CefSharp and ExcelDNA](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/exceldna/PflxmqgvMkw)".

Of course, given this is a CefSharp-specific problem, another alternative is to use something else instead, like [CefGlue](https://bitbucket.org/xilium/xilium.cefglue/src) or [ChromiumFx](https://bitbucket.org/chromiumfx/chromiumfx/overview), for example.

Comment: Oh my gosh this issue of Cefsharp known since 8 May 2014 but still not fixed :)          Thank for your reply @Caio Proiete